# Angular2: File input control label keeps its state after destroying component

Tags: html, angular, forms

I have an Angular2 component (lets call it `dataset-create`) which includes a form:

```
<form novalidate="novalidate">
    <button type="button" (click)="onClose()">close</button>
    <button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit()">submit</button>
    <label for="dataFileD">data</label>
    <input id="dataFileD" type="file" (change)="onFileChange($event)">
</form>
```

The `close()` and `submit()` functions emit a `(close)` event which makes the parent component to disable the `dataset-create` component:

```
<div [ngSwitch]="mode">
    <template [ngSwitchWhen]="'create'">
        <dataset-create [dataset]="dataset" (close)="onDatasetFormClose()"></dataset-create>
    </template>
    <template [ngSwitchWhen]="'detail'">
        <dataset-detail [dataset]="dataset" (close)="onDatasetFormClose()"></dataset-detail>
    </template>
</div>
```

This is done bone by binding the emitted `(close)` event of the `dataset-create` component to the following function in the parent component:

```
private onDatasetFormClose() {
    this.mode = "list";
}
```

So here are my first question: Every time the `mode` variable toggles between `'create'` and something else the `dataset-create` component is created and destroyed. Correct? Correct! I verified it by adding a `console.log("foo");` in the constuctor on the `dataset-create` component.

Here is my problem now: If the above is correct, why the label of the file input keeps it's value after submitting (thus destroying the `dataset-create` component) the form?

To make things more clear here are the steps I follow:

- I set somehow `mode` variable to `'create'`. The `dataset-create` component is constructed. The file input button has now the label `No file chosen`.
- I click the file input button and choose a file (lets say, `foo.png`). The file input label now has the label `foo.png`.
- I click the submit button on the form. The `dataset-create` component is destroyed.
- I set somehow `mode` variable to `'create'`. The `dataset-create` component is constructed. **The file input button has now the label `foo.png`. Why? Why the label of the  file input control keeps its previous state?**

Comment: What angular2 version are you using?

Comment: Oh you are right, I totally forgot about that. I was using beta0. I just updated to beta1 and the problem fixed itself! If you can add a short answer saying that this is a beta0 bug I will accept it as correct. Thanks man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @AstrOne

This was the behavior until beta.0. Angular2 used to reuse the created DOM (see [#4478](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4478), [#5188](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5188), among others). As a workaround we had to use `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` to tell angular2 not to cache the DOM.

Since beta.1 this is no longer an issue, and using `APP_VIEW_POOL_CAPACITY` is no longer necessary. As part of [#5993](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/5993) every DOM node is recreated propertly (see @tbosch's [comment](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5500#issuecomment-167901800)).

Comment: Are u sure it is no longer a problem ? Updated to 2.0.0-beta.6, and I have the same problem with ngSwitch :(